Question Regarding I.F. of limits
My calculus class has already gone over indeterminate forms, l'Hospital rule, etc. and I am preparing for an exam. One thing I don't understand in my professor's notes, is a part of the following sum rules for limits of two functions:

$$\begin{aligned}&\textbf{1. Sum: }\lim_{x\to a}(f+g)=\lim_{x\to
> a}f+\lim_{x\to a}g\text{ with the following “calculation
> rules”:}\\&\bullet+\infty+L=+\infty\ \\&\bullet(-\infty)-(-\infty)=-\infty\\&\bullet\:(L_{1})+(L_{2})=L_{1}+L_{2}\\&\bullet\:(+\infty)+(+\infty)=+\infty\end{aligned}$$

Specifically, I don't understand how $(−∞)−(−∞)=−∞??$
To me, these seems like it would lead to $(−∞)+∞$, which is an indeterminate form. What am I missing here?
In the very same notes by my professor, the following are defined as indeterminate:

$$\begin{array}{cccc}1.&\infty-\infty&5.&0^0\\2.&0\cdot\infty&6.&\infty^0\\3.&0/0&7.&1^\infty\\4.&\infty/\infty\end{array}$$

If someone could provide an example or give an insight into how $(−∞)−(−∞)=−∞$ holds true, it would be greatly appreciated. I haven't run into it in any exercises, but I can't wrap my head around what this means.

That looks like a typo.

It doesn't make sense right? Maybe it should have been something like (−∞)−(+∞)=−∞

Or $(-\infty) +(-\infty)=-\infty$.

Ok, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't crazy lol

You should easily be able to construct examples of the form $(-\infty)-(-\infty)$ which resolve to $-\infty, +\infty$ or to any finite value you desire or which fail to achieve any limit at all.
